# System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code error

Tags: c#, sql, .net, stored-procedures

this issue has been discussed earlier here but that doesn't help me to solve my problem.

here is my stored procedure below to make an investment inactive.

```
ALTER  procedure [dbo].[mark_inactive]                  
@order_id int,                 
@intResult int output                  
as                  
BEGIN transaction               

Declare @Error as int

update investment_orders set investment_active = 0 where order_id = @order_id


-- if error in saving details                    
Select @Error = @@error                    
 if(@Error<>0)                    
 Begin                    
  Set @intResult = 0                    
  rollback transaction            
  return                      
 End          
commit transaction                    
return @intResult
```

and Code-behind function to call procedure

```
 public int ExecuteSqlSP(SqlParameter[] arrParam, string strSPName)
    {
        OpenConnection();
        _mDataCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        _mDataCom.CommandText = strSPName;
        _mDataCom.CommandTimeout = 30;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrParam.Length; i++)
        {
            _mDataCom.Parameters.Add(arrParam[i]);
        }

        _mDataCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        int intResult = Int32.Parse(_mDataCom.Parameters["@intResult"].Value.ToString());
        CloseConnection();
        DisposeConnection();
        return intResult;
    }
```

Although one row is updated but the following error showing

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

I am sorry if any mistakes. Please help me to solve the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Which line does the error occur on? ExecuteNonQuery or the Int32.Parse?

Comment: thanks for your reply. Int32.Parse section returning error

Comment: I'd check the contents of your out parameter first and ensure it has a value before attempting a parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning any value from the stored procedure you've written after successful update.

you procedure should be look like

```
ALTER  procedure [dbo].[mark_inactive]                  
@order_id int,                 
@intResult int output                  
as                  
BEGIN transaction               

Declare @Error as int

update investment_orders set investment_active = 0 where order_id = @order_id;
SET @intResult = 1; // 1 OR whatever desired value you wanna return

-- if error in saving details                    
Select @Error = @@error                    
 if(@Error<>0)                    
 Begin                    
  Set @intResult = 0                    
  rollback transaction            
  return                      
 End          
commit transaction                    
return @intResult
```

Comment: @bangla Tiger - I’m glad it worked!! Kindly mark it as Helpful answer so it would be helpful for others too!! :)

Comment: - I am new here and dont know how to mark it as Helpful. Will you please tell me?